# SSO Login with Chrome Custom tabs

Tags: android, single-sign-on, deep-linking, chrome-custom-tabs

In my app, I need to do login through a web page. On successful log-in it is returning in the header of the response as "my-app:/auth?code=xxxxxx&status=xxxxx". I configured a custom schema in my APP.

**Code to open Chrome custom tab:**

```
StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(<url>);
        url=url.append("&response_type=code");
        url=url.append("&redirect_uri=");
        url=url.append("my-app:/auth");
        CustomTabsSession session = getSession();
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        intentBuilder.setShowTitle(true);
        intentBuilder.setNavigationBarColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        intentBuilder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        intentBuilder.setSession(session);
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent=intentBuilder.build();
        CustomTabsHelper.addKeepAliveExtra(this, customTabsIntent.intent);
        CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(this, customTabsIntent, Uri.parse(url.toString()),
                (activity, uri1) -> {
                    showProgressDialog();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("screen_type", type);
                    LoginWebViewFragment loginWebViewFragment = LoginWebViewFragment.getInstance();
                    loginWebViewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    startNewFragment(loginWebViewFragment, "LoginWebViewFragment");
                });
```

**Schema configured in Manifest file:**

```
<activity
            android:name="<myActivity>"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/transparent_status_bar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="my-app" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

After a successful login, the App is not opening. Is this possible to redirect from the Chrome custom tab to App?

Answer (score 2):

You missed a slash in your redirect URI: `my-app:/auth` should be `my-app://auth`

Comment: When I typed in Firefox browser app my-app:/auth  or my-app:/auth then it is redirecting to my APP, but if I type in Chrome app then it is not working for both. So I am confused if chrome supports custom schema to open an APP

Comment: You've still typed one slash both times.  Chrome definitely supports custom schemes, though I haven't tested this exact format.  I think Chrome also might behaves differently if you type the URL in directly - might be worth trying clicking a link and seeing if it opens your app.

Comment: I think Chrome does not support custom schema now, I just found doc for it, check                             https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: Chrome does support custom schemes. From the blogpost: *"...Instead, you should implement a user gesture to launch the app **via a custom scheme**, or use the “intent:” syntax described in this article..."*.  This blogpost explains how to do OAuth with Custom Tabs: https://medium.com/@ajinkyabadve/do-authentication-in-android-using-custom-chrome-tab-cct-2a0edffc93fd